# How do I search for an asterisk in the search?

Tags: whatsapp

I often write corrected sentences to people starting with an *.

I need to find all of these messages, but am having no luck.

How can I search for all my messages starting with the asterisk character?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Whatsapp. Due to the high amount of indexing required

After performing several tests I have reached the following conclusions

- Whatsapp Requires a minimum of **two** characters before it even attempts a search
- At least **one** of these characters **must** be a letter or a number

[image: All tests performed using Whatsapp web app]

so if you know even the first letter of the correction you were trying to make e.g *appple and searched for *a it would come up. A possible workaround would be to perform 24 searches using every letter of the alphabet following *

Answer (score 0):

whatsapp search is not as good as it should be. For me it will search if the characters are followed by " "(space). If you search for $ for example, it wont show messages with $100 for example.

To answert your question, you cannot search this unless you mention other text as well e.g. *hi